# Deletion of several tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I believe the following tags should be deleted since there are no questions that use them.

- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)
- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags)
- [limits](/questions/tagged/limits)
- [scraping](/questions/tagged/scraping)

Comment: The `tag-cleanup-request` is about tags on the main site. In addition to that, if you want to direct people to meta tags, use `[meta-tag:something]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can't delete tags, they are auto deleted by the system every now and then.

Also, you can point to a random tag, system will show the standard tag page, but it doesn't necessarily mean that they exist.. (ex: [data-explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) doesn't exist, neither does [scraping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scraping) or [interesting-tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags))

Comment: He's talking about tags on meta

Comment: ah damn, my bad.

Comment: Well, if you see a wiki (or a link to create a wiki), it means that the tag still exists. If you don't see an option to create a tag wiki or edit the existing one, it means that the tag does not exist at all.